# IOS, XCODE , Orientation

Tags: ios, xcode

---

Orientation of the view does not change when "Orientation" under "Simulated Metrics" is changed. I am not sure what else I should be providing for the view to rotate. I suspect that I am missing some really small, like checking in a box which would allow this to happen, but not sure what.

Comment: Check General Build settings for all the rotations you need to enable.

Comment: But I have already done all that, still no luck. I remember I was able to do this in Xcode 6.3, that is where I started and now I am using 7. Not sure what else I should be providing. I have provided all the possible rotations in the target --> general --> orientations. Also I have checked the build settings for anymore options that I might have left by chance, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Very easy.

1) Click on Target

2) Go to General Tab

3) In Device Orientation --> Check an orientation type you want.

That's it!!

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for the response. But I have already done all that, still no luck. I remember I was able to do this in Xcode 6.3, that is where I started and now I am using 7. Not sure what else I should be providing.